# Google apps script CAN'T store attachment addons

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to know how to store something when you use check box and later access it when checkbox state changes.

I tried store array as global but when script runs again what i stored is reseted to empty array.

I also tried propeties but it can only store strings.
So if anybody know how to store attachments i would be glad.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways on how this can be approached. Either you can store data to a spreadsheet and build scripts based on the Google Sheet Data by referring to this [document.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

If it's a file were talking about you can use `DriveApp` using the method `createFile()` from a given Blob of arbitrary data. [Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app).

Or, you can connect to an external database using JDBC Service as reference here in this [documentation.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc)